# Retrieving Icon/image of a file/folder (CentOS)

Tags: c, gtk

Can anybody suggest me how to retrieve icon or image of a folder that is created newly?
Please note that I am using GTK & C on CentOS, where I have a situation like this:
programmatically I create folder using `mkdir()` system call. When a new folder is created, I need to find the icon that is created for this folder from GUI perspective and I don't know where the image/icon is loaded from. 
For example, we generally use `GdkPixbuf` functions to display/overlay icon. So my problem is, when a new file/folder is created, how would I get the icon that is created for them (who will create those icons) so that I can make use of icon's path and do an overlay on it using `GdkPixbuf`?

If more details needed, please revert back.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks nos. Would you please let me know GUI applications as how they display folders with a particular icon?

Comment: The icon will depend on the mime type and the icon theme... And themes work differently on GTK 2 and GTK 3. Which GTK version is using your CentOS ?